# ValueError at /setupuser/ invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ekatech'

Tags: python, django

i given charfield to organiztion but it is giving error int()with base 10.I followed the django documentation and tried different ways but not working. plz help
input i given for organization is "ekatech"

views.py

```
def set_user(request):

if request.method == "POST":

    form = Set_User_Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        organization=form.cleaned_data.get('organization')
        email_id=form.cleaned_data.get('email_id')
        Designation=form.cleaned_data.get("Designation")
        job_level=form.cleaned_data.get("job_level")
        emails_for_help=form.cleaned_data.get("share_email_with")
        instance=Setup_user(organization,email_id,Designation,job_level,emails_for_help)
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponse("form saved")
```

forms.py:

```
class Set_User_Form(forms.Form):
organization=forms.CharField(max_length=200)
email_id=forms.EmailField(max_length=30)
CEO = 'CEO'
JCHOICES = (
    (CEO, 'CEO'),
)
Designation=forms.ChoiceField(label="Designation",choices=JCHOICES)
LEVEL1 = "L1",
LCHOICES = (
    (LEVEL1, "Level 1"),
)

job_level=forms.ChoiceField(label="Job level",choices=LCHOICES)
share_email_with= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label="share Knowledge with", queryset=User.objects.all(),widget= forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
class Meta:
    model = Setup_user
```

models.py

```
 class Setup_user(models.Model):
 organization=models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,default="not
given")
email_id=models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
CEO = 'CEO'
JCHOICES = (
    (CEO, 'CEO'),)
Designation = models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=JCHOICES)
LEVEL1 = "L1"
LCHOICES = (
    (LEVEL1,"Level 1"),
)
job_level=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=LCHOICES)
emails_for_help=models.CharField(max_length=2000,null=True)
```

**ERROR:**

```
 ValueError at /setupuser/
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ekatech'
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/setupuser/
 Django Version:    2.0.3
 Exception Type:    ValueError
 Exception Value:   
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ekatech'
```

Comment: Please properly format your code, provide an example of inputs, and provide the complete error. Based on the code you provided, I don't think the problem comes from `organization`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of inheriting forms.form i went through another approach of modelform

```
class Set_User_Form(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model=Setup_user
    fields=["organization","email_id","Designation","job_level","emails_for_help"]
```

and for view inherited formview....issue got resolved.